# disadvantages of storing secrets in Blob Storage

Tags: azure-keyvault

My current customer has secrets stored in Blob Storage and we want to propose them to migrate to KeyVault. May I know what are the benefits or storing secrets into KeyVault as compared to Blob?

When I read the documentation, KeyVault uses the HSM to protect the keys and secrets but Blob also uses the encryption which is also secure. so what are the other advantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that in general they look very similar, however I'd say the most important difference between the two would be the authorization model.

Access to a storage account is done by one of the two available connectionstrings/keys. Access to a KeyVault can be assigned directly to users or groups (from AAD) and the access to resources within the Key vault can be configured with more granularity. Next to that it is very easy to limit the type of resources from within azure that may or may not retrieve data from a KeyVault, reducing the attack service.

Storage accounts do have AAD integration currently in preview, but what i gather is that that is mostly focusing on the Azure file share functionality (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview).

Another nice differentiation is definitely the integrations that are already available when using KeyVault (i.e. Retrieving Azure DevOps secrets directly from a KeyVault or automatically retrieving Certificates for VMs)

FYI, i'm by no means a KeyVault expert but that's just my 2 cents :)

Comment: Thank you so much. can you please elaborate this point: "Next to that it is very easy to limit the type of resources from within azure that may or may not retrieve data from a KeyVault, reducing the attack service."?

Comment: As i don't know what type of secrets you are storing in the KeyVault i'm not sure what  would be useful to you, but if you look at the 'access policies' section in the Azure portal (this is also where you assign permissions to users) you actually have to enable access to the KeyVault for certain types of operation (i.e. whether or not Azure Resource Manager or VM deployments may access it). attack service is also limited a lot by the granularity of the permission structure for users. i'd advise creating users/service principles for different uses of the secrets keeping it all clean and clear